# tweepy - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, oauth, module, tweepy

I have a script in Python to collect data with Tweepy.
When I run it, I got this message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'; 'tweepy' is not a package`
I've made a pip install tweepy and my python's version is 3.8.0.
Here is the beginning of my code (written on sublime Text):

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler


consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = "XXX"
access_token = "XXX"
access_token_secret = "xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Where's my mystake? Thank you

Comment: try `pip3 install tweepy`

Comment: Hi, no " pip3  install tweepy  "  doesn't work   even if i have upgraded my pip version

Comment: The error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'; 'tweepy' is not a package` leads me to believe `tweepy` already exists. But it is not the PyPI `tweepy`. Do you have a python file named `tweepy.py`? Please also include the output of `pip3 freeze` in your question.

Comment: Hi ,  no my file is not named  " tweepy.py"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not importing OAuthHandler? You might not need to. Tweepy's documentation recommends:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael is spot on.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler <<- your error is here


consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = "XXX"
access_token = "XXX"
access_token_secret = "xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) <<-- and here
# this should be:
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30972068)